# Numerical integration in Python involving four dimensions

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm trying to obtain the following `S2` from a given `S1`,

$$
S2(i, j) =
\sum _{k=0} ^i
\sum _{l=0} ^j
S1(k, i-k, j, l)
e^{
  -\sqrt{-1} (i-k)^2 (j-l)
}
$$

and I've written the following code using four loops. However, when I increase the parameter `N`, the computation becomes too slow.

```
import numpy as np

N=3
S1=np.arange(N**4).reshape(N,N,N,N)
S2=np.zeros((N,N),dtype ='complex_')

for i in range(N):
     for j in range(N):
          for k in range(i+1):
               for l in range(j+1):
                    S2[i,j]+=S1[k,i-k,j,l]*np.exp(-1j*(i-k)**2*(j-l))
```

Are there more fast methods without using the loops, such as numpy's trace?
For the `k` summation, by inverse-ordering `0` axis or `1` axis for `S1`, `trace` seemed to be available with `i-N` as the offset with weight of the exponential, but a tuple cannot be the offset.

Comment: How is this "without using loops"?  I see four `for` loops in the code.  I think your summary title is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be vectorised, and when that's done it does run faster, though the time complexity does not improve and is still O(n^4). The proposed implementation has a speedup of roughly 35x.

Your current algorithm - which is a reasonable first step prior to optimisation - uses nested loops and direct indices. Whereas it computes fewer elements when compared to a fully-vectorised multiplication with pre- and post-triangularisation, the latter is more efficient at scale.

Recognise that the following three expressions:

- `for k in range(i+1)`
- `for l in range(j+1)`
- `S1[k,i-k,j,l]`

all imply triangular matrices. Triangularising `S1` can be done with a partial assignment to an initially-zero matrix using modified `triu_indices`. Triangularising the `k` and `l` assignments can be done after your calculation with a `tril` call.

A quick profile shows that the heart of the calculation - the Euler-form `exp(i*theta)` - is the bottleneck. Euler-form polar space calculations in Numpy are slow. Convert this to a rectangular expression and calculate the `cos` and `sin` in two halves of a contiguous array.

Further optimisations may be possible where you calculate only the non-zero segment and then reshape it. I have not shown this.

### Suggested

```
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import cProfile

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def old_integrate(S1: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    N = S1.shape[0]
    S2 = np.zeros((N, N), dtype='complex_')

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(i + 1):
                for l in range(j + 1):
                    S2[i, j] += S1[k, i - k, j, l] * np.exp(-1j * (i - k) ** 2 * (j - l))

    return S2


def slide_s1(S1: np.ndarray, N: int) -> np.ndarray:
    # Achieve the effect of S1[k, i-k, :, :]
    S1_slid = np.zeros_like(S1)
    k, i = np.triu_indices(N)
    S1_slid[i, k, :, :] = S1[k, i-k, :, :]
    return S1_slid


def addend_expr(
    S1_slid: np.ndarray,
    i_minus_k: np.ndarray,
    j_minus_l: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    # return S1_slid * np.exp(-1j * (i_minus_k**2 * j_minus_l)) #  820 ms

    '''theta = i_minus_k**2 * j_minus_l  # 437 ms
    result = S1_slid * (
        np.cos(theta) - 1j * np.sin(theta)
    )
    return result'''

    # 268 ms
    theta = -i_minus_k**2 * j_minus_l
    rect = np.empty((*S1_slid.shape, 2), dtype=np.float64)
    np.cos(theta, out=rect[..., 0])
    np.sin(theta, out=rect[..., 1])
    as_complex = rect.view(dtype=np.complex128)[..., 0]
    as_complex *= S1_slid
    return as_complex


def make_addends(S1_slid: np.ndarray, N: int):
    # Numeric indices over any of the dimensions
    idx = np.arange(N)

    # Broadcast index difference to two-dimensional matrix
    idx_diff = idx[:, np.newaxis] - idx

    # Four-dimensional term: (j - l)
    j_minus_l = idx_diff[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, :]

    # Four-dimensional term: (i - k)
    i_minus_k = idx_diff[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]

    # Full addends before triangularisation
    addends = addend_expr(S1_slid, i_minus_k, j_minus_l)

    # Triangularise
    return np.tril(addends)


def integrate(S1: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    N = S1.shape[0]
    S1_slid = slide_s1(S1, N)
    addends = make_addends(S1_slid, N)

    # sum ("integrate").
    S2 = np.sum(addends, axis=(1, 3))
    return S2


def synthetic(N: int) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.arange(N**4).reshape((N, N, N, N))


def test() -> None:
    # Regression test.

    # Original input data
    N = 3
    S1 = synthetic(N)

    s2_expected = np.array((
        (  0,   7.00000000 +  0.00000000j,  21.00000000 +  0.00000000j),
        ( 36,  80.48362767 - 10.09765182j, 121.40263435 - 27.10299716j),
        (108, 184.34527389 - 16.92451601j, 238.92174068 - 79.19827981j),
    ))

    for method in (old_integrate, integrate):
        S2 = method(S1)
        assert np.allclose(S2, s2_expected, rtol=1e-10, atol=0)


def profile() -> None:
    N = 60
    cProfile.runctx(
        'integrate(S1)',
        locals={
            'S1': synthetic(N),
        },
        globals=globals(),
        sort='tottime',
    )


def compare() -> None:
    times = []

    for n in np.round(10**np.linspace(0.5, 1.6, 5)):
        S1 = synthetic(int(n))
        for method in (old_integrate, integrate):
            def run():
                return method(S1)
            t = timeit(run, number=1)
            times.append((n, method.__name__, t))

    df = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=('n', 'method', 't'))
    ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='n', hue='method', y='t')
    ax.set(xscale='log', yscale='log')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    profile()
    compare()
```

### Output

```
         99 function calls (96 primitive calls) in 0.357 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.264    0.264    0.264    0.264 274360.py:32(addend_expr)
      8/5    0.049    0.006    0.061    0.012 {built-in method numpy.core._multiarray_umath.implement_array_function}
        1    0.012    0.012    0.012    0.012 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        1    0.012    0.012    0.357    0.357 <string>:1(<module>)
```

[image: time complexity]

Comment: For the expressions ```S1[k,i-k,j,l]``` and  ```for k in range(i+1)```, aren't the two corresponding triangularizings are equivalent? Then, further triangularizing for ```for k in range(i+1)``` is not necessary.

Comment: @user16308 You're right! Thanks; edited.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the answer

Comment: When the ```N``` is increased a lot to ~200, which is the case I am studying, the memory problem may pop up, only for the vectorisation, not for the explicit for loops. I may need to figure out how the vectorisations can avoid the memory problem.